# (C++) Merge Sort Execution Time

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I found a code online about measuring the execution time of merge sort. I couldn't understand the part where the values are put in the array. In the line: b[i] = i + 352; What is the value 352 is for? What would be the next value if I want an array size of 2000, 3000, 4000 and so on.

```
        int b[1000];
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 1001; i++) {
            b[i] = i + 352 ;
            } //put values into array

        int n = sizeof b / sizeof b[0];

        clock_t start = clock();
        merge_sort(b, n);
        clock_t end = clock();

        double elapsed1 = ((end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);// seconds elapse
        printf("Time elapsed for merge 1000: %f\n", elapsed1);
```

Answer (score 0):

352 is just a integer literal.It is just storing the value i+352 at b[i],so b[0] will have value 352,b[1] will have value 353 and so on.Also if you further increase the array size to 2000 then arr[1999] will contain 1999+352.

One better way to compute the running time of any program might be this one..
cmd /v:on /c "echo !TIME! & youprogram.exe & echo !TIME!"